# How to separate a json data in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I am very new to js, now i have a json data which was passed by backend to my js file. The json data is like the following:

```
{
Vivo:{Time:[20190610,20190611],Price:[2000,2000]},
Huawei:{Time:[20190610,20190611],Price:[3000,3000]},
Maxvalue:3000
}
```

the json data i get is by the following code:

```
fetch('/Tmall') //Tmall is the url i go to fetch data
.then(function(response) {
return response.json();
}).then(function(Data) {

...
}
```

Next I will process the data to present at the front-end, but i don't know how to assign the Data to two different argument:

```
Cellphone = 
{
Vivo:{Time:[20190610,20190611],Price:[2000,2000]},
Huawei:{Time:[20190610,20190611],Price:[3000,3000]}
}

Max = {Maxvalue:3000}
```

Here is what i tried to do, i used if-is the key to separate the data from the original one, but it dosen't work

```
    var Cellphone = {}
    for (var i = 0; i < Data.length; i++)
    {
      if (Data.key[i] != 'Maxvalue'){
        Cellphone.push(Data[i])
      }
    }
```

Comment: What should the output be?

Comment: Access an object's data with dot notation: `let Cellphone = { Vivo: Data.Vivo, Huawei: Data.Huawei };` and `let Max = Data.Maxvalue;`.

Comment: @ZivBen-Or How is this a duplicate?

Comment: @JackBashford The second last code block is the output i want :) the last code block i wrote is only deal with the cellphone part. in reality i actually have multiple cellphone infos need to deal with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) combined with [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Code:

```js
// Your `Data` response...
const Data = {Vivo:{Time:[20190610,20190611],Price:[2000,2000]},Huawei:{Time:[20190610,20190611],Price:[3000,3000]},Maxvalue:3000};

// Logic
const Cellphone = Object.keys(Data)
  .filter(k => k !== 'Maxvalue')
  .map(k => ({ [k]: Data[k] }));
const Max = { Maxvalue: Data.Maxvalue };

console.log('Cellphone:', Cellphone);
console.log('Max:', Max);
```

Comment: Hi is "k" a reserved word? or in filter() or map() it can be automatically identified as a variable to iterate through the parameter? i have no idea how machine can realize what k is here

Comment: @TileiLiu `k` is a variable name.. The current element being processed in the array of keys

Comment: is it adaptable if i replace 'k' with  'a','b','c' .... or even a word like 'element'?

Comment: Yes, that is right.. I used `k` because referring to the object `keys` but you can use any variable name

Answer (score 2):

Just extract the `Maxvalue` property, and assign the others to `Cellphone`. This is really simple with destructuring and spreading:

```js
const data = {
  Vivo: {
    Time: [20190610, 20190611],
    Price: [2000, 2000]
  },
  Huawei: {
    Time: [20190610, 20190611],
    Price: [3000, 3000]
  },
  Maxvalue: 3000
};

const { Maxvalue: Max, ...Cellphone } = data;
console.log("Max:", Max);
console.log("Cellphone:", Cellphone);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: HI~I don't get what is this mean "const { Maxvalue: Max, ...Cellphone } = data;"

Comment: The `const {...} = data` means we're extracting object properties. The `Maxvalue: Max` makes a new variable called `Max` and gives it the value of `data.Maxvalue`. The `...Cellphone` makes a new object called `Cellphone` with all the rest of the properties in `data`.

Comment: Hi i put the code in my js file, yet it still dosen't work. is it because instead of an const my "Data" is actually a object?

Answer (score 1):

You can individually pick out the max value, save it in to a variable, then remove it from the object. This will allow you to assign all cellphones to a variable, even if their names change. For example;

```js
let data = {
  Vivo:{Time:[20190610,20190611],Price:[2000,2000]},
  Huawei:{Time:[20190610,20190611],Price:[3000,3000]},
  Maxvalue:3000
}

// save the maxValue key
let maxValue = data.Maxvalue;

// then remove it from the object
delete(data.Maxvalue);

// the remaining keys are cellphones
let cellPhones = data;

console.log(maxValue, cellPhones);
```

Comment: Thank you! it's also a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the function, where you set `Data` as a parameter, do the following

```
let Cellphone = {
    Vivo: Data.Vivo,
    Huawei: Data.Huawei
};
let Max = Data.Maxvalue;
```

Comment: What if the cellphone names change?

Comment: Capital case in js  usually using for class

Answer (score 0):

The following code should solve your problem

```js
var phones = {};
var max;
Object.entries(data).forEach(function (entry) {
  if (entry[0] == "Maxvalue") {
    max = entry[1];
  }
  else {
    phones[entry[0]] = entry[1];
  }
});
console.log("Phones: ", phones);
console.log("Max: ", max)
```